# warning on CGBitmapContextCreate

Tags: iphone, ios

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace([UIImage imageNamed:@"shirtWhite.jpeg"]); 
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate (nil,
                                                  width,
                                                  height,
                                                  CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageToTest.image),
                                                  CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageToTest.image),
                                                  colorSpace,
                                                  CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageToTest.image));
```

I got the warning on each line where I am passing the image.
The warning is " warning: passing argument 1 of 'CGImageGetColorSpace' from incompatible pointer type

warning: passing argument 1 of 'CGImageGetBitsPerComponent' from incompatible pointer type

"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: pass CGImage instead of image